# CMake goes into an infinite loop when there are two stand-alone subprojects with two different compilers within the same build

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, clang, clang++

I am new to `CMake`. What I want to have is two different stand-alone subprojects within one "root" project such that those two subprojects could be built independently. Given that those two subprojects use two different type of compilers.

Let's start with the directory structure, it looks like this:

```bash
project/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── subproject01
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── subproject01.c
└── subproject02
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── subproject02.cpp
```

The root `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21...3.27 FATAL_ERROR)

project(project DESCRIPTION "A project")

add_subdirectory(subproject01)
add_subdirectory(subproject02)
```

Here, `subproject01` uses `gcc/g++` and the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21...3.27 FATAL_ERROR)

project(subproject01 DESCRIPTION "A sub-project 01")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} MODULE subproject01.c)

install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION project/subproject01
)
```

Where `subproject02` uses `clang/clang++` and the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21...3.27 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")

project(subproject02 DESCRIPTION "A sub-project 02")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} MODULE subproject02.cpp)

install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION project/subproject02
)
```

I can build those two subprojects independently when I invoke `cmake` command within their respective subproject directories.

But when I try to build from root project directory, the `cmake` goes into infinite loop.

```bash
user@pc:~/project$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER= /usr/bin/gcc
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/g++

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
... and so on
```

How do I achieve this? I want two different stand-alone subprojects within one "root" project such that those two subprojects could be built independently or all at once from the root.

In any case, for reproducibility, `subproject01.c` looks like this:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

int function(int);

int function(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

and `subproject02.cpp` looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

double function(double a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

The `cmake` version is `3.26.4`

Comment: @starball Ufortunately no, I was looking for a solution where I will have two separate `CMakeLists.txt` for different subprojects. The example here is just a "minimal reproducible" version of what I was trying to achieve, in the actual case, those two `CMakeLists.txt` will have lots of stuffs in them.

Comment: why doesn't my answer there answer this question then? My answer there says that what you are trying to do is not supported by CMake.

Comment: please show the text of the infinite loop- at least the beginning, one iteration and the part where it begins the next iteration. Show that ouput from a clean configure and build. Show also the output of `cmake --version`.

Comment: @starball Thanks, I didn't see your answer at first, but anyway, I edited my question for more info.

Comment: do you really not set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` in subproject01/CMakeLists.txt? Also, you still haven't explained why my answer there doesn't answer this question.

Comment: It's also rather confusing what you want. Your title states a current unwanted behaviour, but your body makes a statement about a goal, and goes into great detail about an approach that is unsupported, and you don't explain why you won't try what will actually work. Why focus so much on your failed attempt if your question is really about how to achieve your goal? Do you actually want to understand why your attempt has failed? Or to learn how to get what you want (which is not yet fully clear)? Asking for both in one post is rather broad and not good for long-term value in a Q&A entry for SO.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you just want to understand why what you've tried is resulting in the behaviour you've described and how to change it to make it not happen, I can do that (I've already reproduced the issue and determined the cause), but you need to clarify what your question actually is.

Comment: also, though I personally found the explanation for the behaviour you've found interesting as an educational exercise, I'm kind of doubtful of the long-term value of understanding this behaviour. But who knows. Somehow this question got two upvotes quite quickly, so maybe people do care.